# How to delete data from selected Date to current Date using DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, datetime

My problem is to delete data from given date to current date,

My code works fine for deleting the data by the date given in the DateTimePicker.

i want to delete the data from given date in DateTimePicker to CurrentDate.

For example:

1. In subfolder123 the data is available from 20100131 to 20110531 (Date Format `yyyyMMdd`).
2. I want to delete the date from 20100215 to 20110531.

Hope you understood my Question and problem.

Is there any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string todaysDate = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    int FinalDate4 = 0;
    string Destinationnsefx = "C:\\folder\\subfolder\\subfolder123";
    int xyz = 0;
    string SecSym = (9722).ToString();
    MWriterClass writerdelete1 = new MWriterClass();
    try
    {
        writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationnsefx);
        writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSym);
        FinalDate4 = int.Parse(todaysDate);
        if (writerdelete1.get_bDateExists(FinalDate4))
        {
            try
            {
                writerdelete1.DeleteIntradaySecRecordEx(FinalDate4, 080000, 240000);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        writerdelete1.CloseSecurity();
        writerdelete1.CloseDirectory();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you get a date from your DateTime picker and you need to work from that start date to your end date, correct?

In that case, look at the AddDays method for a DateTime object.

For example, this snippet of code will start at 4/1/2011 and print every date from then until today, in the format you specified.

```
        var workingDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1);

        while (workingDate < DateTime.Today)
        {
            workingDate = workingDate.AddDays(1);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", workingDate));
        }
```

Comment: Can You pls Add this in My code and onemorething its in Windows Form Application